# validation with json - ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

If i have this json response

```
{"error":"repeated"}
```

Why the alert is not showed? It is needed put somewhere `dataType: "json"` ?

```
$(function () {
        $("#box a").click(function () {
            var selectedId = $(this).attr("class");

            $.post("new_list.php", {
                id_user: <?php echo $id;?>,
                id_list: selectedId
            }, function (data) {
                   if(data.error == 'repeated') {
                        alert("error");
                   }
            }); 
        }); 
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going to automatically parse it as JSON unless you tell it to.

```
$(function () {
    $("#box a").click(function () {
        var selectedId = $(this).attr("class");

        $.post("new_list.php", {
            id_user: <?php echo $id;?>,
            id_list: selectedId
        }, function (data) {
               if(data.error == 'repeated') {
                    alert("error");
               }
        },
        "json"); //Here, add this as last parameter
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a matter of converting the response string into a Javascript object:

```
function (data) {
    // Parse the JSON
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    if(data.error == 'repeated') {
        alert("error");
    }
}
```

Although you could just use the [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function instead, saving yourself some trouble

Answer (score 0):

Check if your reply is a string instead of an object. Then you must call

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

And use obj.error to check if it is 'repeated'

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
        $("#box a").click(function () {
            var selectedId = $(this).attr("class");

            $.post("new_list.php", {
                id_user: <?php echo $id;?>,
                id_list: selectedId
            }, function (data) {
                   if(data.error == 'repeated') {
                        alert("error");
                   }
            },dataType: "json" ); 
        }); 
    });
```

The following snippet will let jquery know your expecting json.